# Unidentified pneumatic part

Tags: tools

I recently purchased a pneumatic micro die grinder and it came with pretty much no instructions and this piece with some clear plastic that screws inline.  I have no idea what this for.  What is it and when/how do I use it? 
[image: This part]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is an oiler. Air tools with moving parts want a small, but steady mist of oil in the air. With some, like an air nailer, they simply say you can add a couple of drops to the connector before you attach the hose to it. But some tools want a steady fix.

Check out this photo and description over at [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002L9BK48):

[image: Picture of 1/4" mini oiler/lubricator]

Keep in mind, that if you use your oiler with a hose between the oiler and the tool, that hose will now contain oil. While the hose can be used easily with any tool that can tolerate oil, you will not want to use it with any kind of spray painter since water/latex based paint and oil don't mix well.

Comment: Fill the plastic shell with oil made for air tools, and it will keep the grinder works lubricated.